# Override Ansible facts similar to Puppet and Facter override

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

NOTE: Part of Puppet to Ansible migration evaluation. Ansible noob.

CentOS 7 returns `operatingsystemrelease` (puppet) or `ansible_distribution_version` (ansible) as 7.2.1511 instead of just 7.2. So in puppet we use the following hack.

```
# Hack for CentOS 7. operatingsystemrelease includes third part of release version eg 7.2.1511
if [[ "$(facter operatingsystem)" == "CentOS" && "$(facter operatingsystemmajrelease)" == "7" ]]
then
    export FACTER_operatingsystemrelease=$(facter operatingsystemmajrelease).$(facter --json os | grep minor | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr '",' ' ' | sed -e 's/ //g')
fi
```

Setting environment variable `FACTER_operatingsystemrelease` overrides the `operatingsystemrelease` value. This needs to happen only for CentOS 7. CentOS 6 works fine.

What would be the equivalent way to make this work in Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

You can override facts as any other variable:

```
set_fact: ansible_distribution_version="{{ ansible_distribution_version | regex_replace('7\.2\.\d+','7.2') }}"
when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
```

Comment: This needs to be done in playbook under -tasks or hosts? Sorry still learning.

Comment: As I test, I tried running "ansible -m setup -i hosts -u centos -c local --extra-vars "ansible_distribution_version=7.2" localhost", But it still was 7.2.1511.

Comment: Also, is there any way to overwrite any other variable only for one command or one run?